# Python: Calculating taxes program

Tags: python, python-3.x, debugging

I am new to Python and I am trying to figure out how to debug my code below. I am not even sure if I created the four functions correctly. I am trying to use for loop to display all status, income, and tax from the constants and the bracket. How would you guys fix this?

```
SINGLE_BASE0 = 0
SINGLE_BASE1 = 907.50
SINGLE_BASE2 = 5081.25
SINGLE_BASE3 = 18193.75
SINGLE_BASE4 = 45353.75
SINGLE_BASE5 = 117541.25
SINGLE_BASE6 = 118118.75

MARRIED_BASE0 = 0
MARRIED_BASE1 = 1815.0
MARRIED_BASE2 = 10162.5
MARRIED_BASE3 = 28925.0
MARRIED_BASE4 = 50765.0
MARRIED_BASE5 = 109587.5
MARRIED_BASE6 = 127962.5

RATE_0 = .10
RATE_1 = .15
RATE_2 = .25
RATE_3 = .28
RATE_4 = .33
RATE_5 = .35
RATE_6 = .396

SINGLE_BRACKET0 = 0
SINGLE_BRACKET1 = 9075
SINGLE_BRACKET2 = 36900
SINGLE_BRACKET3 = 89350
SINGLE_BRACKET4 = 186350
SINGLE_BRACKET5 = 405100
SINGLE_BRACKET6 = 406750

MARRIED_BRACKET0 = 0
MARRIED_BRACKET1 = 18150
MARRIED_BRACKET2 = 73800
MARRIED_BRACKET3 = 148850 
MARRIED_BRACKET4 = 226850
MARRIED_BRACKET5 = 405100
MARRIED_BRACKET6 = 457600

def is_positive(income_str):
  return income_str.isdigit() and int(income_str) > 0

def is_valid_status(tax_str):
  return tax_str == 's' or tax_str == 'm'

def compute_tax_for_bracket(marital_status, total_income):
  marital_status = ['single', 'married'] 
  total_income = [[SINGLE_BRACKET0,SINGLE_BRACKET1, SINGLE_BRACKET1 + 1,
                   SINGLE_BRACKET2, SINGLE_BRACKET2 + 1,
                   SINGLE_BRACKET3, SINGLE_BRACKET3 + 1,
                   SINGLE_BRACKET4, SINGLE_BRACKET4 + 1,
                   SINGLE_BRACKET5, SINGLE_BRACKET5 + 1,
                   SINGLE_BRACKET6, SINGLE_BRACKET6 + 1],
                  [MARRIED_BRACKET0, MARRIED_BRACKET1, MARRIED_BRACKET1 + 1,
                   MARRIED_BRACKET2, MARRIED_BRACKET2 + 1,
                   MARRIED_BRACKET3, MARRIED_BRACKET3 + 1,
                   MARRIED_BRACKET4, MARRIED_BRACKET4 + 1,
                   MARRIED_BRACKET5, MARRIED_BRACKET5 + 1,
                   MARRIED_BRACKET6, MARRIED_BRACKET6 + 1]]

def compute_tax(tax_str, income_str):  
    status = 'single' or 'married'
    income = int(income_str)
    tax = ""
    for i in range(len(marital_status)):
      status = marital_status[i]
      for j in range(len(total_income[0])):
        income = total_income[i][j]
    if tax_str == 's':
      status = 'single'
      if SINGLE_BRACKET0 <= income <= SINGLE_BRACKET1:
        tax = SINGLE_BASE0 + (RATE_0 * income - SINGLE_BRACKET0 )
      elif SINGLE_BRACKET1 <= income <= SINGLE_BRACKET2:
        tax = (SINGLE_BASE1) + RATE_1 * (income - SINGLE_BRACKET1 )
      elif SINGLE_BRACKET2 <= income <= SINGLE_BRACKET3:
        tax = (SINGLE_BASE2) + RATE_2 * (income - SINGLE_BRACKET2 )
      elif SINGLE_BRACKET3 <= income <= SINGLE_BRACKET4:
        tax = (SINGLE_BASE3) + RATE_3 * (income - SINGLE_BRACKET3 )
      elif SINGLE_BRACKET4 <= income <= SINGLE_BRACKET5:
        tax = (SINGLE_BASE4) + RATE_4 * (income - SINGLE_BRACKET4 )
      elif SINGLE_BRACKET5 <= income <= SINGLE_BRACKET6:
        tax = (SINGLE_BASE5) + RATE_5 * (income - SINGLE_BRACKET5 )
      else:
        tax = (SINGLE_BASE6) + RATE_6 * (income - SINGLE_BRACKET6 )

    if tax_str == 'm':
      status = 'married'
      if MARRIED_BRACKET0 <= income <= MARRIED_BRACKET1:
        tax = MARRIED_BASE0 + (RATE_0 * income - MARRIED_BRACKET0 )
      elif MARRIED_BRACKET1 <= income <= MARRIED_BRACKET2:
        tax = (MARRIED_BASE1) + RATE_1 * (income - MARRIED_BRACKET1 )
      elif MARRIED_BRACKET2 <= income <= MARRIED_BRACKET3:
        tax = (MARRIED_BASE2) + RATE_2 * (income - MARRIED_BRACKET2 )
      elif MARRIED_BRACKET3 <= income <= MARRIED_BRACKET4:
        tax = (MARRIED_BASE3) + RATE_3 * (income - MARRIED_BRACKET3 )
      elif MARRIED_BRACKET4 <= income <= MARRIED_BRACKET5:
        tax = (MARRIED_BASE4) + RATE_4 * (income - MARRIED_BRACKET4 )
      elif MARRIED_BRACKET5 <= income <= MARRIED_BRACKET6:
        tax = (MARRIED_BASE5) + RATE_5 * (income - MARRIED_BRACKET5 )
      else:
        tax = (MARRIED_BASE6) + RATE_6 * (income - MARRIED_BRACKET6 )

    print("%s, $%9.2.f = $%9.2f" % (status, income_str, tax))
    print("Your tax bill, given that you are a {} filer with an income of \
{} is ${}" .format(status, income_str, tax))
    tax_str = input("Enter your marital status (Enter 's' or 'm' only) OR \
press <ENTER> to quit:  ")
    print()

    Calculate_Taxes(tax_str)

def Calculate_Taxes(tax_str):
    while not is_valid_status(tax_str):
      print()
      tax_str = input("Enter your marital status Enter 's' or 'm' only:  ")
    income_str = input("Enter your income:  ")

    while not is_positive(income_str):
      print()
      income_str = input("Income must be a valid amount >= $0.00 \n"
                           "Enter your income:  ")

    compute_tax(tax_str, income_str)

def main():
  print("This program computes the simple tax for single and married fillers.")
  print()

  tax_str = input("Enter your marital status (Enter 's' or 'm' only) OR \
press <ENTER> to quit:  ")

  Calculate_Taxes(tax_str)  

main()
```

As a result of this code, I get NameError obviously. I believe it might work if the functions were combined, but I have to have them separately.

Comment: That is ALOT of code to stare at for probably a minor fix.

Comment: At first you should switch from these less beautiful numbered variables to lists.

Comment: `income_str.isdigit()` will return `False` for `$9075`.

Comment: 1. as stated by @bereal

Comment: 2. Use `return income_str[1:].isdigit() and int(income_str[1:]) > 0` to separate the char `$`

Comment: 3. `TypeError: compute_tax() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given`

Comment: 4.  `print("Your tax bill, given that you are a %7s filer with an income of \
%9.2f is %9.2f" % compute_tax(status, income, tax))` For number 3

Comment: 5. `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'tax' referenced before assignment`

Comment: @DirtyBit I changed that to `print("Your tax bill, given that you are a %7s filer with an income of \
%9.2f is %9.2f" (status, income, tax))` 
and it says 
`TypeError: 'str' object is not callable`

Comment: @balilee you're calling the funciton `compute_tax` within the function itself. It is a **catastrophe**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Continuing from the comments above, there are a few things I would strongly suggest.

1. Use `list` not a `list of variables`
2. You could use only a few loops.
3. There are variables that you are not even using, get rid of them.

**Fix**:

```
SINGLE_BASE0 = 0
SINGLE_BASE1 = 907.50
SINGLE_BASE2 = 5081.25
SINGLE_BASE3 = 18193.75
SINGLE_BASE4 = 45353.75
SINGLE_BASE5 = 117541.25
SINGLE_BASE6 = 118118.75

MARRIED_BASE0 = 0
MARRIED_BASE1 = 1815.0
MARRIED_BASE2 = 10162.5
MARRIED_BASE3 = 28925.0
MARRIED_BASE4 = 50765.0
MARRIED_BASE5 = 109587.5
MARRIED_BASE6 = 127962.5

RATE_0 = .10
RATE_1 = .15
RATE_2 = .25
RATE_3 = .28
RATE_4 = .33
RATE_5 = .35
RATE_6 = .396

SINGLE_BRACKET0 = 0
SINGLE_BRACKET1 = 9075
SINGLE_BRACKET2 = 36900
SINGLE_BRACKET3 = 89350
SINGLE_BRACKET4 = 186350
SINGLE_BRACKET5 = 405100
SINGLE_BRACKET6 = 406750

MARRIED_BRACKET0 = 0
MARRIED_BRACKET1 = 18150
MARRIED_BRACKET2 = 73800
MARRIED_BRACKET3 = 148850
MARRIED_BRACKET4 = 226850
MARRIED_BRACKET5 = 405100
MARRIED_BRACKET6 = 457600

def is_positive(income_str):
    return income_str[1:].isdigit() and int(income_str[1:]) > 0

def is_valid_status(tax_str):
  return tax_str == 's' or 'm'

def compute_tax_for_bracket(marital_status, total_income):
  marital_status = ['single', 'married']
  total_income = [[SINGLE_BRACKET0,SINGLE_BRACKET1, SINGLE_BRACKET1 + 1,
                   SINGLE_BRACKET2, SINGLE_BRACKET2 + 1,
                   SINGLE_BRACKET3, SINGLE_BRACKET3 + 1,
                   SINGLE_BRACKET4, SINGLE_BRACKET4 + 1,
                   SINGLE_BRACKET5, SINGLE_BRACKET5 + 1,
                   SINGLE_BRACKET6, SINGLE_BRACKET6 + 1],
                  [MARRIED_BRACKET0, MARRIED_BRACKET1, MARRIED_BRACKET1 + 1,
                   MARRIED_BRACKET2, MARRIED_BRACKET2 + 1,
                   MARRIED_BRACKET3, MARRIED_BRACKET3 + 1,
                   MARRIED_BRACKET4, MARRIED_BRACKET4 + 1,
                   MARRIED_BRACKET5, MARRIED_BRACKET5 + 1,
                   MARRIED_BRACKET6, MARRIED_BRACKET6 + 1]]

def compute_tax(tax_str, income_str):

    status = 'single' or 'married'
    income = income_str[1:]
    tax = ""
    if tax_str == 's':
      status = 'single'
      if SINGLE_BRACKET0 <= int(income) <= SINGLE_BRACKET1:
        tax = SINGLE_BASE0 + (RATE_0 * int(income) - SINGLE_BRACKET0 )
      elif SINGLE_BRACKET1 <= int(income) <= SINGLE_BRACKET2:
        tax = (SINGLE_BASE1) + RATE_1 * (int(income) - SINGLE_BRACKET1 )
      elif SINGLE_BRACKET2 <= int(income) <= SINGLE_BRACKET3:
        tax = (SINGLE_BASE2) + RATE_2 * (int(income) - SINGLE_BRACKET2 )
      elif SINGLE_BRACKET3 <= int(income) <= SINGLE_BRACKET4:
        tax = (SINGLE_BASE3) + RATE_3 * (int(income) - SINGLE_BRACKET3 )
      elif SINGLE_BRACKET4 <= int(income) <= SINGLE_BRACKET5:
        tax = (SINGLE_BASE4) + RATE_4 * (int(income) - SINGLE_BRACKET4 )
      elif SINGLE_BRACKET5 <= int(income) <= SINGLE_BRACKET6:
        tax = (SINGLE_BASE5) + RATE_5 * (int(income) - SINGLE_BRACKET5 )
      else:
        tax = (SINGLE_BASE6) + RATE_6 * (int(income) - SINGLE_BRACKET6 )

    if tax_str == 'm':
      status = 'married'
      if MARRIED_BRACKET0 <= int(income) <= MARRIED_BRACKET1:
        tax = MARRIED_BASE0 + (RATE_0 * int(income) - MARRIED_BRACKET0 )
      elif MARRIED_BRACKET1 <= int(income) <= MARRIED_BRACKET2:
        tax = (MARRIED_BASE1) + RATE_1 * (int(income) - MARRIED_BRACKET1 )
      elif MARRIED_BRACKET2 <= int(income) <= MARRIED_BRACKET3:
        tax = (MARRIED_BASE2) + RATE_2 * (int(income) - MARRIED_BRACKET2 )
      elif MARRIED_BRACKET3 <= int(income) <= MARRIED_BRACKET4:
        tax = (MARRIED_BASE3) + RATE_3 * (int(income) - MARRIED_BRACKET3 )
      elif MARRIED_BRACKET4 <= int(income) <= MARRIED_BRACKET5:
        tax = (MARRIED_BASE4) + RATE_4 * (int(income) - MARRIED_BRACKET4 )
      elif MARRIED_BRACKET5 <= int(income) <= MARRIED_BRACKET6:
        tax = (MARRIED_BASE5) + RATE_5 * (int(income) - MARRIED_BRACKET5 )
      else:
        tax = (MARRIED_BASE6) + RATE_6 * (int(income) - MARRIED_BRACKET6 )

    print("Your tax bill, given that you are a {} filer with an income of \
{} is ${}".format(status, income_str, tax))

def main():

  print("This program computes the simple tax for single and married fillers.")
  print()
  tax_str = input("Enter your marital status (Enter 's' or 'm' only) OR \
press <ENTER> to quit:  ")

  while not is_valid_status(tax_str):
      print()
      tax_str = input("Enter your marital status Enter 's' or 'm' only:  ")
  income_str = input("Enter your income:  ")

  while not is_positive(income_str):
      print()
      income_str = input("Income must be a valid amount >= $0.00 \n"
                       "Enter your income:  ")

  compute_tax(tax_str, income_str)

  tax_str = input("Enter your marital status (Enter 's' or 'm' only) OR \
press <ENTER> to quit:  ")

main()
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
This program computes the simple tax for single and married fillers.

Enter your marital status (Enter 's' or 'm' only) OR press <ENTER> to quit:  s
Enter your income:  $9075
Your tax bill, given that you are a single filer with an income of $9075 is $907.5
Enter your marital status (Enter 's' or 'm' only) OR press <ENTER> to quit:
```

**EDIT:**

Added a method `Calculate_Taxes(tax_str)` to keep calculating the taxes.

```
def is_positive(income_str):
    return income_str[1:].isdigit() and float(income_str[1:]) > 0

def is_valid_status(tax_str):
  return tax_str == 's' or 'm'

def compute_tax_for_bracket(marital_status, total_income):
  marital_status = ['single', 'married']
  total_income = [[SINGLE_BRACKET0,SINGLE_BRACKET1, SINGLE_BRACKET1 + 1,
                   SINGLE_BRACKET2, SINGLE_BRACKET2 + 1,
                   SINGLE_BRACKET3, SINGLE_BRACKET3 + 1,
                   SINGLE_BRACKET4, SINGLE_BRACKET4 + 1,
                   SINGLE_BRACKET5, SINGLE_BRACKET5 + 1,
                   SINGLE_BRACKET6, SINGLE_BRACKET6 + 1],
                  [MARRIED_BRACKET0, MARRIED_BRACKET1, MARRIED_BRACKET1 + 1,
                   MARRIED_BRACKET2, MARRIED_BRACKET2 + 1,
                   MARRIED_BRACKET3, MARRIED_BRACKET3 + 1,
                   MARRIED_BRACKET4, MARRIED_BRACKET4 + 1,
                   MARRIED_BRACKET5, MARRIED_BRACKET5 + 1,
                   MARRIED_BRACKET6, MARRIED_BRACKET6 + 1]]

def compute_tax(tax_str, income_str):

    status = 'single' or 'married'
    income = income_str[1:]
    tax = ""
    if tax_str == 's':
      status = 'single'
      if SINGLE_BRACKET0 <= int(income) <= SINGLE_BRACKET1:
        tax = SINGLE_BASE0 + (RATE_0 * int(income) - SINGLE_BRACKET0 )
      elif SINGLE_BRACKET1 <= int(income) <= SINGLE_BRACKET2:
        tax = (SINGLE_BASE1) + RATE_1 * (int(income) - SINGLE_BRACKET1 )
      elif SINGLE_BRACKET2 <= int(income) <= SINGLE_BRACKET3:
        tax = (SINGLE_BASE2) + RATE_2 * (int(income) - SINGLE_BRACKET2 )
      elif SINGLE_BRACKET3 <= int(income) <= SINGLE_BRACKET4:
        tax = (SINGLE_BASE3) + RATE_3 * (int(income) - SINGLE_BRACKET3 )
      elif SINGLE_BRACKET4 <= int(income) <= SINGLE_BRACKET5:
        tax = (SINGLE_BASE4) + RATE_4 * (int(income) - SINGLE_BRACKET4 )
      elif SINGLE_BRACKET5 <= int(income) <= SINGLE_BRACKET6:
        tax = (SINGLE_BASE5) + RATE_5 * (int(income) - SINGLE_BRACKET5 )
      else:
        tax = (SINGLE_BASE6) + RATE_6 * (int(income) - SINGLE_BRACKET6 )

    if tax_str == 'm':
      status = 'married'
      if MARRIED_BRACKET0 <= int(income) <= MARRIED_BRACKET1:
        tax = MARRIED_BASE0 + (RATE_0 * int(income) - MARRIED_BRACKET0 )
      elif MARRIED_BRACKET1 <= int(income) <= MARRIED_BRACKET2:
        tax = (MARRIED_BASE1) + RATE_1 * (int(income) - MARRIED_BRACKET1 )
      elif MARRIED_BRACKET2 <= int(income) <= MARRIED_BRACKET3:
        tax = (MARRIED_BASE2) + RATE_2 * (int(income) - MARRIED_BRACKET2 )
      elif MARRIED_BRACKET3 <= int(income) <= MARRIED_BRACKET4:
        tax = (MARRIED_BASE3) + RATE_3 * (int(income) - MARRIED_BRACKET3 )
      elif MARRIED_BRACKET4 <= int(income) <= MARRIED_BRACKET5:
        tax = (MARRIED_BASE4) + RATE_4 * (int(income) - MARRIED_BRACKET4 )
      elif MARRIED_BRACKET5 <= int(income) <= MARRIED_BRACKET6:
        tax = (MARRIED_BASE5) + RATE_5 * (int(income) - MARRIED_BRACKET5 )
      else:
        tax = (MARRIED_BASE6) + RATE_6 * (int(income) - MARRIED_BRACKET6 )

    print("Your tax bill, given that you are a {} filer with an income of \
{} is ${}".format(status, income_str, tax))
    tax_str = input("Enter your marital status Enter 's' or 'm' only or q/Q to exit:  ")
    if tax_str == 'Q'.lower():
        exit()
    else:
        Calculate_Taxes(tax_str)


def Calculate_Taxes(tax_str):
    while not is_valid_status(tax_str):
        print()
        tax_str = input("Enter your marital status Enter 's' or 'm' only:  ")
    income_str = input("Enter your income:  ")

    while not is_positive(income_str):
        print()
        income_str = input("Income must be a valid amount >= $0.00 \n"
                           "Enter your income:  ")

    compute_tax(tax_str, income_str)

def main():

  print("This program computes the simple tax for single and married fillers.")
  print()
  tax_str = input("Enter your marital status (Enter 's' or 'm' only) OR \
press <ENTER> to quit:  ")

  Calculate_Taxes(tax_str)

main()
```

Comment: lastly, how do you make it continuously work? because it stops when I enter a word again.

Comment: @balilee What do you mean by continuously work? and what do you enter when it stops?

Comment: I mean I want to continuously compute the tax. 
`This program computes the simple tax for single and married fillers.

Enter your marital status (Enter 's' or 'm' only) OR press <ENTER> to quit:  s
Enter your income:  $9075
Your tax bill, given that you are a single filer with an income of $9075 is $907.5
Enter your marital status (Enter 's' or 'm' only) OR press <ENTER> to quit: ` Like, if I type s or m in the last line, it stops.

Comment: @balilee you could add a method to call within `compute_tax`, editing in a moment.

Comment: Thx a lot. I appreciate it.

Comment: I am sorry but how would you use for loop to compute all income taxes using `print("%s,  $%9.2.f = $%9.2f" % (status, income_str, tax))`

Comment: for example, the output would be `s,  $0.00 = $0.00` `s, $9075.00 = $907.50` `s, $9076.00 = $907.65` and so on

Comment: @balilee Do you wish to add those taxes?

Comment: Yes I do want to add them

Comment: Create a var on top perhaps, `sum_taxes = 0` and then do `sum_taxes += tax`, inside the `for-loop` and before the `print`

Comment: I followed your instructions but it is not working. I think I am doing something wrong.

Comment: `for i in range(len(marital_status)):
    status = marital_status[i]

    for j in range(len(total_income[0])):
      income = total_income[i][j]` I tried this `for-loop` and didn't work

Answer (score 0):

You are stuck into the first while-loop `while is_valid_status(tax_str):`. I think you don't even need it, you should keep the 2 while separately.

```
while not is_valid_status(tax_str):
  print()
  tax_str = input("Enter your marital status Enter 's' or 'm' only:  ")

income_str = input("Enter your income:  ")
while not is_positive(income_str):
  print()
  income_str = input("Income must be a valid amount >= $0.00 \n"
                   "Enter your income:  ")

compute_tax(tax_str, income_str)
```

Comment: And of course the function `is_valid_status`  is wrong. `tax_str == 's' or 'm'` will be computed as `(tax_str == 's') or 'm'` and this will always return a _trueish_ value.